# Why won't SQL Server allow creation of a user with SQL Server Authentication?

Tags: sql-server

I've get a fresh install of SQL Server 2012 and do not want to use integrated security.  Instead I'd like to use SQL Server authentication, where I create logins in SQL server and assign passwords.  However, this option doesn't seem to be available (see screen snapshot below).  Every option available to me under "User Type" (other than those that aren't related to accounts at all) want me to map to existing Windows Domain accounts.

In the old days, I'd specify a desired login name and be prompted for a password to go along with it, and I'd be done.  Now there's no option to specify a password--I'm forced to map my new login to an existing
windows domain account.  Not what I want.  What am I missing here?  Thanks in advance.

** edit ** New screen snapshots added after RB's comment.  I did indeed have an option disabled that would allow BOTH Windows and SQL Server authentication modes, but it's turned on now.  After doing so and restarting SQL Server, it is NOT making a difference:
[image]

Here is what I am presented with when I try to create a new user.  None of these options simply allow me to create a login and password in the context of SQL server (well, one allows creation of a login with no password at all... useless!)  All others are linked to existing Windows logins.  Ideas?

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you haven't enabled mixed mode authentication. Check out this MSDN article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188670(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks RB.  That was a good lead.  I checked it thinking it was the sure solution but came up empty.  I updated my OP with screen snapshots showing what has been done.  Appreciate your input.

Comment: What's wrong with *SQL user with login* right above the *SQL user without login* you have selected?

Comment: Ken, "Sql User with login" forces you to map to an existing user. The little box with ellipses takes you to a lookup box that make you look up an existing user.  I don't want to do that.  I want to create a user name, and I want to enter a password of my own choosing for this user.  Nowhere here do I see the option to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do this in a way that doesn't require pictures and right-clicking.

1. `CREATE LOGIN [yourUserName] WITH PASSWORD = 'someStrongPassword';`
2. `CREATE USER [yourUserName];`